# Context argument and Identifier in Android API

Tags: java, android

When I check for camera existence on Android phone, I start with the following function:

```
public static boolean deviceHasCamera(Context context)
{
    if ( context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(Packa geManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

My question is, why should I pass `context` as an argument and what is Context Identifier?

Answer (score 1):

`Context` provides you access to system resources. Without having a `Context` you cannot get many things from your system such as package manager, strings, colors, dimensions, system services such as `LayoutInflater` and so on. You also can't start any android component such as `Activity` or `Service`. So you should always think about it when designing the architecture of the app.

There are 3 types of context in android: `Activity`, `Application`, `Service`. Also, there are `BroadcastReceiver` and `ContentProvider` that don't extend `Context` directly but they have contexts inside.